# Finding values of an array in a loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

This works! BUT if my JSON returns 200 programs, this will also print all those 200 programs. BUT I want to change the helper method in a way that it **only return TOP 5  that their ercentage is the highest.**

How Can I modify my helper method to achieve this?

P.S: I know probably the best and professional way of doing this is working with "scope" and "order",etc in the Model files or the ActiveRecord query interfaced that actually creates the JSON...but that is for now way out of my leauge!  Wanted to get this done with baby steps...that for later...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try the following

```
def patient_counts(program)
  sorted = program.patient_counts.sort { |a, b| b.money <=> a.money }
  sorted[0..4]
end
```

UPDATE: limiting to just 5 records fetched from the db

```
def patient_counts(program)
  program.registry_patient_counts.limit(5).order('patient_count_percentage DESC')
end
```

Comment: thanks man you helping me a couple time so far on SO but this method didn't change anything.

Comment: can you give more details about why it didn't work? i don't have any clue what `program.patient_counts` return but based on your code, it returns an array of patients which have a money method.  did you get any errors?

Comment: I didn't get any error but for example I changed it to sorted[0..1] to see if it returns two things, but it still returned the three things that I have in DB.  Give me five minutes and I will give more details with picture and code and JSON sample.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: Ok jvnill, I updated my question with your code from your answer and basically posted the real code that I am dealing with in the EDIT section of the question...please take a look. Thank A LOT.

Comment: i'm not sure if it will make a difference (I'd be surprised if it did) but can you try my updated answer?

Comment: thank you so much for helping me, it is like two days I am desperately trying to solve this..But No, your updated answer didn't fix it either, basically nothing changed in compare to the output of the json picture I has posted :(

Comment: I think it is because the controller starts with Organization.includes ... so those limit commands are getting applied to the Organization and not to the Program.

Comment: I'll give you 2000 points if we could get this fixed . seriously.

Comment: hey I created a sample app (so I can also try jbuilder :D and i'm lovin it).  https://github.com/jvnill/jbuilder_test can you try to not use the helper? if you want you can edit the code on that app so we more or less have the same code but what's in that is working.

Comment: Ok sure...thanks man.  Please note that the best way of solving this is through applying stuff to the model. So I created a more clear question of the problems I am having in here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15184182/writing-scope-join-and-order-for-a-model   If it is just easier to answer that one, I would even love it better, because that's the professional way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Create a hash with patients as the key, and patients.money as the value. This could be accomplished with something like:

```
unsorted_patients = { }
program.patient_counts.each do |patient|
    sorted_patients[patient] = patient.money
end
```

Then use sort_by to sort the hash into a 2d array:

```
sorted_patients = unsorted_patients.sort_by { |patient, money| money }
sorted_patients.reverse!
```

The first five elements of sorted_patients will now be 2-element arrays containing the five patients with the most money, and how much money they have, something like this:

```
[[<Bob>, 150000], [<Mary>, 138000], [<Joe>, 125000],...]
```

You should be able to easily extract the needed information from that.

Comment: how about the "top 5" part of it?

Comment: updated to explain that part too. It might be obvious, but just to be clear, <Bob>, etc., are placeholders for whatever type of object patient is.

Comment: I also updated my question with a full context of what I am asking, if you have a sec please take a look from the EDIT part in my question.  Much appreciated.