# Writing scope, join and order for a Model

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-activerecord

My model is like this:

**Program**  `has_many`  **Measures**
and then
**Measures** `has_many` **Targets**
and **Target** table has a column named `value`

My query is like this:

```
@programs2 = Program.includes([measures: :targets])
               .some_scope
               .where('organization_id = 1')
               .limit(2)
```

I don't know where or how to write the `some_scope` part of the query.
The query starts with `Program.includes` so I think it should be defined in the Program model but the problem I have is that `measures: :targets` . How do I define a join for them. If it was just one table I know I can do like this:

```
scope :salary, :joins => :registry,   :order => "money DESC"
```

I need something similar for this one too, but this has has two tables like I explained above. I don't know how to write that one.

Comment: Please stop [duping](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15183785/scope-that-has-three-levels-deep-joins) your question. As soon as somebody is able to answer, the answer will appear.

Comment: @mudasobwa : Sorry, I was trying to you know approach the same question from different views or ways that I can explain it. I think this one is the most clear and explained version of the problem I am having tho :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
scope :some_scope, joins(mesures: :targets)
```

Comment: Thanks but I get this error: PG::Error: ERROR:  zero-length delimited identifier at or near """"

Comment: Is it so bad in I give up and code it this way instead:
Program.joins(measures: :targets).where(organization_id: params[:id]).limit(2) ?

Comment: Yeah tat would be better unless you are trying to access the contents of measures and targets.

Comment: by "that would be better"  which one do you refer to? my second approach that I posted in comments? I want to list some values from the Target table and Name of those values but the NAME of values lives in Measures table.

Comment: Okay. then u need to include, `Program.includes(measures: :targets).where(organization_id: params[:id]).limit(2)`

Comment: I will try it and let you know. Right now I am gonna with the one I could get it work to at least make sure I have something to show to the Boss on Monday!  Once I get this down I will move to better practices like that one.